# equal condition is not working properly in groupby mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoid, mongodb-query

equal condition ($eq) is not working properly in mongo db.  below is my mongo db document(table).

```
{  
"_id":ObjectId("55b08b169d735e293624504a"),
"a":[  
    {  
        "acid":139,
        "akey":"love",
        "atp":"abcd",
        "aadd":" ",
        "adur":3073
    }
],
"created":    ISODate("2015-07-23T06:35:02.959    Z")
```

}

My Query is

```
[  
{  
    "$match":{  
        "created":{  
            "$gte":                ISODate("2015-01-19T07:26:49.045                Z"),
            "$lte":                ISODate("2015-08-20T07:37:56.045                Z")
        }
    }
},
{  
    "$match":{  
        "cid":{  
            $nin:[  
                "59290C6FCCB7E82BD3861F9B6EB46930_2017dec8-0c2c-40c5-9c33-4e3ced0d692f",
                "F098F7DBEFCBAE3ED0E815DE694F2307_8fbe1abc-0d11-443d-bd0a-bf5f181673de",
                "9BAE0D8CA2A3B4BB641C8CCA2A0BD935_d7a76cf4-eb42-41f8-a851-06dd25269fbf"
            ]
        }
    }
},
{  
    "$unwind":"$a"
},
{  
    $group:{  
        _id:"$a.acid",
        "PrestoBarImpression":{  
            "$sum":{  
                "$cond":[  
                    {  
                        "$eq":[  
                            "$a.atp",
                            "abcd"
                        ]
                    },
                    "$total",
                    1
                ]
            }
        },
        "entries":{  
            $sum:1
        }
    }
}
```

]

I am getting the following output .

```
{  
"result":[  
    {  
        "_id":139,
        "PrestoBarImpression":0,
        "entries":1.0000000000000000
    }
],
"ok":1.0000000000000000
```

}

If I put ne instead of eq I am getting desired output as impressions are 1 and entries are 1.

Please let me know what I did mistake in the query

Comment: There is no "total" field in your documents. Which field are you actually intending to add up? And why would the false condition be 1?

Comment: HI @BlakesSeven Its not total its $sum Sorry

Comment: I'm taking about the field "inside" the `$sum` condition of Prestobar impression. It does exist in your sample document. Neither does "cid", which also has no reason to be in a separate `$match` stage. Going by the likelihood here that you are trying to total a field that does not exist. Hence the `0`.

Comment: So what is the problem then? Do you mean to total another field you haven't listed or do you mean something else entirely? Naming fields in two places that do not appear to be in your document leaves this somewhat a mystery. Do you need to add more information to your question or what is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[`$eq`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/)** operator works by comparing two values and returns true when the values are equivalent, false when the values are not equivalent. Thus in your **[`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)** operator, when the **[`$eq`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/)** operator expression evaluates to true, **[`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)** should return a value of 1 and if the **[`$eq`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/)** expression evaluates to false then it should return 0 so that the accumulator operator **[`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)** gives you the actual total.

As a result your **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline stage should look like this:

```
{  
    $group: {  
        _id: "$a.acid",
        "PrestoBarImpression": {  
            "$sum": {  
                "$cond": [  
                    {  
                        "$eq": [ "$a.atp", "abcd" ]
                    },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "entries": { $sum: 1 }
    }
}
```